# how to lock global data and its mutex as a reference object?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, pthreads, locking, critical-section

Can some one explain whats wrong in below code?

```
struct CSection {
    CSection( pthread_mutex_t* mP )     {
        m_lockPtr = mP;
        pthread_mutex_lock( m_lockPtr );
    }
    ~CSection()     {
        pthread_mutex_unlock( m_lockPtr );
    }

    pthread_mutex_t* m_lockPtr;
};

////////////////MAIN CODE ///////////////////
std::list<ABC> gMap;
pthread_mutex_t gMut;
 

//MultiThread API call
push(const ABC& obj) {
    pthread_mutex_t& lock = gMut;
    std::list<ABC>& m = gMap;
    {
        CSection CC (lock);
        m.push_back(obj);
    }
}
```

Above is just a code snippet/sample.
Please explain is it ok to create local reference object and then call crticial section code ?
if not ok then kindly elaborate what will go wrong with above code.

Comment: I think creating a reference object outside critical section is not a good idea and it will have race condition but reference object is also holding same memory address for pthread_mutex_t object then what can go wrong here, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

> Please explain is it ok to create local reference object and then call crticial section code ?

It's unclear what problem you suppose there might be.  In comments you mention a data race, but it's unclear why you think that accessing either mutex or protected data through a reference would inherently create any more risk of a data race than accessing them directly would present.  A reference, including a reference to a mutex, is a functional stand-in for the object bound to it.

Comment: So I mentioned of data race because two threads will hold local reference object of mutex respectively and then critical section will be applied. I'm not sure if this can lead to any problem or not thats why I asked to be 100% sure. 
If answer is yes then should I change code to :
push() { 
    {
        CSection CC (gMut);
        gMap.push_back(obj);
    }

Comment: @vicky, have you noticed that all the pthreads mutex functions accept *pointers to* the mutex to operate upon?  That creates an analogous situation in the body of each of those functions.  It is not a problem.That there are multiple lvalues in different scopes that are all associated with the same object is not particularly uncommon, and does not carry any inherent risk.